# Генератор списка в объявлении статического атрибута класса

Tags: python, классы, генераторы

Генератор в статическом атрибуте класса не видит другой статический атрибут этого же класса.
Для z0 всё нормально работает,
для z1 ругается на первый item "NameError: name 'item' is not defined.":

```
class ListGen:
  item=10
  z0=[10 for i in range(item)]
  z1=[item for i in range(item)]
```

Что для z1 тут сделано не так не пойму? Почему в range() передаёт item, а здесь не видит?

Comment: [Accessing class variables from a list comprehension in the class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition)

Comment: А вообще такие вещи проще делаются: `z1=[item]*item`